# SQLAlchemy - unique records insertion

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a working API that has a function of inserting records to the database. The problem is, it inserts any record on top, not checking for duplicates/whether the record already exists.

What would be the most performant way to do it with that plugging?

I am using SQLAlchemy as this is my company's standard (especially that we work on gcp) but I am not that familiar with that library, and searching I couldn't find anything useful.

My current code is:

```
def db_push(insert: dict)->dict:
    def insert_results(results):
        rows = []
        for i in results:
            rows.append(
                {
                    "name": i["Name"],
                    "id": i["id"],
                    "amount": I["amount"],
                    "invoice" : I["invoice"],
                    "country" : i["Country"]
                }
            )
        return rows

    insert = insert_results(insert)
    conn = engine.connect()
    m = MetaData()
    m.reflect(engine)
    customers = m.tables["customers"]
    _ = conn.execute(customers .insert(), insert)
    conn.close()
```

where get_engine just creates an engine instance ( sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ) with user/pass etc configurations.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I think there are a couple of things that need clarification here. 1. What's the natural key of your "customers" table? Or a little less precisely, what are the combinations of columns that should be considered unique? Would it be "id" + "invoice"? (I'm a little surprised that it has "invoice" and "amount" as columns because I'd expect to find those in something like an "invoices" table.) 2. Can we expect the dictionary being passed in (`insert` is the name, but I'd suggest revisiting that) to contain unique records? Can we expect it to follow the unique restraint I've described in question1?

Comment: @captnsupremo thanks for replying, sorry, I should've clarified, I'd like to have it unique by id and name. Invoice is another dict that stores addresses etc but that's not really relevant here.

Comment: @captnsupremo Dictionary passed in insert is just a response. It will contain record that is currently requested, so it will not be not always unique, ie there is possibility that it is already stored in db so doesn't require to be pushed again.

Comment: Your table should have a unique constraint or a unique index on the relevant columns to ensure that duplicates *cannot* be inserted.